# nesting handsontable inside handsontable

Tags: handsontable

The documentation says that handsontable is one of cell types but the example only shows how to display it as a dropdown. Can I show a cell which has set of sub-cells inside it while preserving navigation model?

Let's say I have two cells: A1 is number, A2 is handsontable with 2*2 grid. When I am on A1 and press right, I want to go to A2(1,1). Another right click brings me to A2(2,1) and then out of A2.

Comment: You might be able to make a custom renderer.